# Link to App Review Tab in iOS6 App Store

Tags: hyperlink, app-store, ios6

Can anyone share a link that will take a user directly from inside an iOS app to the 'Review' tab for the App on the iOS6 App Store?

All the current answers on here and across the web seem to be iOS4/5 specific and/or only take you to the 'Details' tab in the iOS6 App Store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one. just change the app ID in the code. this has worked for me before. it worked under 4.3 but since i don't use this type of approach anymore i can't say for sure that this might work for you.

```
NSString *str = @"itms-
apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?
type=Purple+Software&id=337064413"; //replace the id param's value with your App's id

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

hope this helps. adrian

Comment: Thanks Adrian works perfectly on the iOS6 App Store for now at least!